# Trouble showing articles on Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, blogs

I created a form to create articles, but I can only see the published articles on the index page, and, I'm unable to see individual articles.

Every time I click on 'show' for an individual article on the index, it opens a blank page with a URL like `localhost:3000/articles.1`, instead of `localhost:3000/articles/1`.

I don't know what's wrong with the code, it's similar to the code I have for creating and editing articles as admin and it works there, but I keep getting this error.

Here's the code:

views/articles/show.html.erb:

```
<h1><%= @article.name %></h1>   
<%= @article.content %>
<%= image_tag @article.photo.url(:small) %>

<p>Tags: <%= raw article.tag_list.map { |t| link_to t, tag_path(t) }.join(', ') %></p>
<%= link_to 'Back', noticias_path %>
```

views/articles/index.html.erb:

```
<% @articles.each do |article| %>
  <div>
  <h2><%= article.name %></h2>
  <%= article.content %>
  <p><%= link_to 'Show', noticias_path(article) %></p>
  <p>Tags: <%= raw article.tag_list.map { |t| link_to t, tag_path(t) }.join(', ') %></p>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

articles_controller.rb:

```
# GET /articles/1
# GET /articles/1.json
def show
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
end
```

routes.rb:

```
Blog::Application.routes.draw do 
  root to: 'welcome#index'
  get 'tags/:tag', to: 'noticias#index', as: :tag 
  get "noticias/index"
  get "dashboard/index" 
  get "/sitemap" => "sitemap#index", :as => :sitemap, :defaults => {:format => :xml} 
  match '/noticias', to: 'noticias#index', via: 'get' 
  get 'login', to: 'sessions#new', as: 'login' 
  get 'logout', to: 'sessions#destroy', as: 'logout' 
  resources :users 
  resources :sessions 
  namespace :admin do
    get '', to: 'dashboard#index', as: '/' 
    resources :noticias 
  end 
end
```

Comment: show your `routes.rb`

Comment: @LuisLago I posted your routes.rb in the question for you. You can just edit the question next time instead of pasting it in the comments; its very difficult to read otherwise.

Comment: thanks, i'll remember that next time

Answer (score 1):

It's more a problem with `noticias_path`, consider verify your routes with `rake routes`, but I think to change `noticias_path` to `noticia_path`, may can fixed it.

Comment: No, it doesn't fix it. In routes I have this `match '/noticias', to: 'articles#index', via: 'get'`. I created the forms in English because I was following some tutorials in English, but then I created a route to Notícias because the site will be in Portuguese. Should I change "articles" to "noticias" in all the code to avoid this problem?

Comment: @LuisLago For clarification, do you mean that you *only* have that index route, and nothing else (meaning you don't have a line that points to the `show` action)? This does indeed sound like a routing problem, but you'll have to post your entire routes.rb in order for us to see. If you renamed some routes and such to Portuguese, it sounds like its possible you may have missed something.

Comment: @LuisLago, can you post the contents of routes.rb for clarification?

Comment: `Blog::Application.routes.draw do
   root to: 'welcome#index'
get 'tags/:tag', to: 'noticias#index', as: :tag
  get "noticias/index"
  get "dashboard/index"
get "/sitemap" => "sitemap#index", :as => :sitemap, :defaults => {:format => :xml}
  match '/noticias', to: 'noticias#index', via: 'get'
  get 'login', to: 'sessions#new', as: 'login'
  get 'logout', to: 'sessions#destroy', as: 'logout'
  resources :users
  resources :sessions
  namespace :admin do
   get '', to: 'dashboard#index', as: '/'
   resources :noticias
  end
end`

Comment: sorry for that, but there's no line pointing to the `show` action in the routes.rb

Answer (score 0):

Based on your routes file, it looks like the problem is indeed incorrect routing. Presently, you are manually creating routes for RESTful resources, when you should simply let rails handle that for you properly.

Remove the manual `get` and `match` lines:

```
get "noticias/index"

match '/noticias', to: 'noticias#index', via: 'get'
```

And replace them with this:

```
resources :noticias
```

If `noticias` should be pointing to the `ArticlesController` (or any other controller), then simply do this:

```
resources :noticias, to: 'articles'
```

Also, Matheus Caceres was correct that the URL helper should in fact be `noticia_path` for the `show` action. The `noticias_path` points to the `index` action. Rails tries to be "helpful" by making routes, helpers, functions, etc, sound proper if read in English, but might not necessarily make sense for words in another language. I don't know if "noticia" makes any sense in Portuguese though.

Another quick side note, the two manual routing lines I indicated above are redundant; they would in fact both match a `GET` request and route them to `noticias#index`. However, keep in mind that routes are matched in the order they appear in the routing file, so the `match` line would never have been called, since the route would have matched on that `get` line.